# How to hash the password during update in mongodb using bcrypto in express.js?

Tags: express

I want to hash the the password during the update process. I have done hashing of password during save. But during update the pre hook is not supported in **mongodb**. How can i hash the password if password has been changed during update in express.js using **bcrypt** and **mongoose.**

Comment: The [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) states that if you require middleware to get called on update, you need to rewrite your code to first perform a `.find()/.findOne()` and calling `.save()` on the updated instance.